# python regex to replace body of functions in C

Tags: python, c, regex, stack

Lets have a functions in C like this:

```
int main(){
    if(1){
      printf("1");
   }
}
```

What I need is to find the function body in `{ }` and replace it with empty string. This bothers me because of the `{ }`, which can be nested infinitely. Is there a way to find bodies like this or I will have to use the stack, or some variables to store the nesting.

Comment: You cannot do it with just regex. Since regex is context insensitive. Like you said you can maintain a count of { and then you should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is a regex learning project undertaken solely for interest you should consider taking a more professional approach. You appear to have decided that regex is the appropriate approach without considering alternatives.

I'd suggest looking at using something like [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser), which will do all the heavy lifting for you and present the program in a form that makes it easy to do what you want.

Comment: Well I cannot use non-standard libraries.

Comment: @gragas01 then the task is impossible unless it implies writing a C parser.

Comment: So it's a made up problem by some lecturer and you are looking for help with homework? Better to be honest and say so if that's the case